# Taking only 1 on 3 <tr>

Tags: python, xpath

I'm actually parsing website to extract data in Python using Xpaths.

But I don't know how to this thing :

```
<tr> </tr>
<tr> </tr>
<tr> Data </tr>
<tr> </tr>
<tr> </tr>
<tr> Data </tr>
<tr> </tr>
<tr> </tr>
<tr> Data </tr>
```

I know I can do `//tr[3]` to get the thrid one. But how can I do to get all thirds ?

Comment: So you want the lines with `<tr> Data </tr>` right ?

Comment: Yes, all the <tr> with data in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use position funxtion and take the remainder of the division by 3. Because xpath understand zero as false, you can write

```
//tr[not(position() mod 3)]
```

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`position()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) function:

```
//tr[position() mod 3 = 0]
```